# erlang - quicksort. The standard quicksort program from learnyousomeerlang

Tags: syntax, erlang, quicksort

What is the difference? why am i getting only first element in list?

```
    -module(hello).
-export(quicksort/1,                                                                                 
    lc_quicksort/1]).

quicksort([]) -> []; 
quicksort([Pivot|Rest]) ->
    quicksort([x || x <- Rest, x =< Pivot])
    ++[Pivot]
    ++ quicksort([y || y <- Rest, y > Pivot]).

lc_quicksort([]) -> []; 
lc_quicksort([Pivot|Rest]) ->
lc_quicksort([Smaller || Smaller <- Rest, Smaller =< Pivot])
++ [Pivot] ++
lc_quicksort([Larger || Larger <- Rest, Larger > Pivot]).



1> c("hello.erl").

{ok,hello}

2> hello:quicksort([3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 9]).

[3]

3>  hello:lc_quicksort([3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 9]).

[1,2,3,4,5,9]
```

What am i missing? Posting this to learn that functionality of erlang that I missed while learning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first letter of a variable must be uppercase like `Rest` or `Smaller`. `x` and `y` in your function are `atom`s.

```
quicksort([]) -> []; 
quicksort([Pivot|Rest]) ->
    quicksort([X || X <- Rest, X =< Pivot])
    ++[Pivot]
    ++ quicksort([Y || Y <- Rest, Y > Pivot]).
```